# Using both .isDisplayed and .isEnabled?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

Intro: I'm making automated tests with appium and I'm fairly new to it.
Newbie question: Is there any point making double assertions for elements using is.Displayed and .isEnabled?

Comment: Of-coarse there is. Where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: I was just wondering if .isEnabled covers both. I'm not sure if it's possible for example to have an element which is enabled but not displayed? I'm excluding cases with elements popping up after some animation or an action. I'm talking more in the context of bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assertion `.isEnabled` means that the element is not disabled, to clarify this here is sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Enabled: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Disabled: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

First input is `enabled` and second is `disabled`, but both of them are `displayed`. But it could be also like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Not displayed and enabled: <input type="text" name="fname" style = "display: none"><br>
  Displayed and enabled: <input type="text" name="fname" style = "display: inline-block"><br>
  Not displayed and disabled: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled style = "display: none"><br>
  Displayed and disabled: <input type="text" name="lname" disabled style = "display: inline-block"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Therefore there are different assertions for `Selenium` for different test cases. If you want a combination of both `.isDisplayed` and `.isEnabled`, use `.elementToBeClickable`. More information in [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed--)(JAVA)

Comment: So should I presume that if it's enabled it's always displayed? In which case using both assertions isn't useful.

Comment: `Not displayed and enabled: <input type="text" name="fname" style = "display: none"><br>` in this case no, run the code snipets to see the difference ))

Comment: In which case using both assertions isn't useful? Well, as I said already, you can just use `.elementToBeClickable` to make sure that element is `displayed` and `enabled`. There is no need to make two assertions.

Comment: If it's clackable, it is enabled and displayed. If you are satisfied with my help, please mark my answer by clicking on grey check button below the downvote button.